# Countable/ uncountable

Tags: grammar, countable-nouns, countability

1. I have got many (chairs/ cases), so will you help me carry them upstairs?
2. This good and near (hotel/accommodation) to stay in.

If you have to choose between chairs and cases in the first sentence, which one will you choose? I will go for "cases", but I think we can use "chairs" in some contexts, do you agree with me?

In the second sentence, if I have to choose between hotel and accommodation, I will go for accommodation because it is uncountable, but hotel is countable and we need to use either "the" or "a". Does what I mentioned make sense to everyone? To be honest, sentence number two does not sound correct to me because the verb is missing, do you agree with me??

Thanks in advance

Comment: I disagree with you. Cases and chairs are different things. The second sentence is wrong not only for the lack of a verb. "This is a good hotel to stay in". What did you intend to say by using **near**? And accommodation is a different word.

Comment: I know that they are different things, but it was a question in the exam. Does using chairs sound correct to you too depending on the context? And what about the second sentence?

Comment: The first question doesn't make any sense and SovereignSun explained why.  Either *chairs* or *cases* could be correct there.  The second question doesn't make sense because the whole sentence is grammatically incorrect, but I guess "accomodation" is a better choice because "hotel" would require an article.  Frankly, if these are questions on an exam, you should tell the school that it fails at English!

Comment: Idiomatically it's completely unacceptable to use the collocation ***good and near*** as a "compound prepositive adjective". There's the extremely slangy adverbial usage *I punched him good and hard,* but even that would be very unlikely to occur before the noun as *I gave him a good and hard punch.*

Comment: @stangdon: I'm having trouble understanding how anyone could find themselves in the position of having such meaningless questions presented as an "exam". I can't even hazard a guess as to what the incompetent examiners think they're testing, let alone what they think the "right" answers might be.